# Кросскомпиляция на GO. Исполняемый файл в килобайтах

Tags: golang, компиляция, кросс-компиляция

На Linux установлен gccgo компилятор, который выдаёт результат в килобайтах.

Для создания исполняемого файла для Windows сидя на Linux использую команду :  `GOOS=windows GOARCH=386 go build first.go -o result.exe`

Не удовлетворяет размер получаемого файла по сравнению с командой `gccgo -o result first.go`.

`GOOS=windows GOARCH=386 go build first.go -o result.exe` - 1.8 мегабайт.
`gccgo -o result first.go` - 33.1 килобайт.

**Вопрос** : Как сделать так, чтобы создался исполняемый файл с килобайтовым размером для Windows ?

Comment: Вы точно используете gccgo, а не go для кросс-компиляции? ЕМНИП, при прямом вызове gccgo игнорирует GOOS и GOARCH.

Comment: @Ainar-G, ошиблась.

Answer (score 1):

У вас тут две проблемы. Во-первых, на Линуксе ваш бинарь gccgo линкует динамически:

```
$ ldd hello 
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffe67d8b000)
    libgo.so.9 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgo.so.9 (0x00007f47f19d5000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f47f17bf000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f47f13f5000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f47f2fa5000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f47f11d8000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f47f0ecf000)
```

Инструмент go же по умолчанию создаёт статически слинкованные бинарники, у которых нет внешних зависимостей.

Во-вторых, кросс-компиляция с gccgo — [дело нелёгкое](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/GccgoCrossCompilation), а преимуществ он — сужу из практического опыта — практически не предоставляет. Так что я рекомендую использовать инструмент go и линковать статически везде, где возможно.